# outputting Access data to multiple Excel worksheets via VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a database that outputs 4 reports to Excel. These are all in different workbooks. 
However I would like to output these all to one template workbook but in different worksheets.

Any help would be appreciated.

Chris

Comment: Is there existing code to output the reports to Excel? If so, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19431037/edit) your question to show it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I'm using late binding here.

```
Private Sub OutputToExcel()
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oBook As Object
    Dim oSheet As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    oExcel.Visible = True
    Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add 'default workbook has 3 sheets
    Set oSheet = oBook.worksheets(1)
    oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Test " & oSheet.Name
    Set oSheet = oBook.worksheets(2)
    oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Test " & oSheet.Name
    Set oSheet = oBook.worksheets(3)
    oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Test " & oSheet.Name
    Set oSheet = oBook.worksheets.Add
    oSheet.Name = "Test Sheet4"
    oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Test " & oSheet.Name

    Set oSheet = Nothing
    Set oBook = Nothing
    Set oExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```